# iOS Firebase with SQLCipher leads to EXC_BAD_ACCESS

Tags: ios, firebase, sqlite, cocoapods, sqlcipher

I have a strange problem. I use SQLCipher in my app, integrated with Cocoapods. 
Now I try to add Firebase, especially Analytics. But when Firebase is included

`...
pod 'SQLCipher'
pod 'Firebase'
...`

and I do nothing more, don't configure Firebase etc. SQLite throws randomly **EXC_BAD_ACCESS**.

Sometimes when the app call's `sqlite3_prepare_v2`, `sqlite3_step` or many other `sqlite3` methods.

But when I remove Firebase from the project, everything works fine again

Comment: You should review and implement the changes in these tw advisories: https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/important-advisory-sqlcipher-with-xcode-8-and-new-sdks/1688 and https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/important-advisory-sqlcipher-with-xcode-9-and-new-sdks/2371

Comment: thanks! a correct setup was the solution :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was an incomplete project setup.

> - When using SQLCipher Commercial Edition static libraries: $(PROJECT_DIR)/sqlcipher-static-ios/ios-libs/libsqlcipher-ios.a (adjust according to the the path to the libsqlcipher-ios.a you received as part of the package).
> - When using the sqlcipher.xcodeproj included in the SQLCipher git repository: $(BUILT_PRODUCTS_DIR)/libsqlcipher.a
> - When using the SQLCipher CocoaPod with the use_frameworks Podfile setting enabled: -framework SQLCipher
> - When using the SQLCipher CocoaPod without the use_frameworks Podfile setting enabled: -lSQLCipher

https://discuss.zetetic.net/t/important-advisory-sqlcipher-with-xcode-8-and-new-sdks/1688